# How to show whole list from xml file in DataGrid window form?

Tags: c#, xml, datagrid

I have a problem to show more than 1 row in my datagrid table. If you have any solution for my problem, please help.

Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        XmlReader xmlFile;
        xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("ORD_BS_734_1499_20180515_1318.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);
        for (var i = 1; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)
        {
            ds.Merge(ds.Tables[i]);
        }
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        //dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;

        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Here is my XML:

```
<Item>
  <GTIN>35715475984623</GTIN>
  <CustomerArticleIdLC>75681</CustomerArticleIdLC>
  <CustomerArticleIdSAP>70000505</CustomerArticleIdSAP>
  <ArticleName>VODA VODA</ArticleName>
  <Quantity>96</Quantity>
  <UOM>KOM</UOM>
</Item>
```

Comment: The ReadXml() method only works when you have a limited number of nested tags in the Xml.  The root tag is the Dataset name.  The 2nd level tags are the Table names.  The third level tags are the column names and the 4th level tags are the rows of data.  When you have more than 4 levels the ReadXml() method fragments the tables so they are unusable.   So you need to manually parse the Xml using XmlDocumnet class or XDocument class.  Done it lots of times before bu need sample of the xml.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of data from the XML file?

Comment: Here is my XML: 

<Item>
      <GTIN>35715475984623</GTIN>
      <CustomerArticleIdLC>75681</CustomerArticleIdLC>
      <CustomerArticleIdSAP>70000505</CustomerArticleIdSAP>
      <ArticleName>VODA VODA</ArticleName>
      <Quantity>96</Quantity>
      <UOM>KOM</UOM> </Item>